# Нумерация листьев в дереве

Tags: c#

Дан класс, описанный следующим образом:

```
public class Node
{
  string name;
  int id;
  List<Node> children;
}
```

Как занумеровать каждый узел уникальным значением. Желательно чтобы дочерние узлы отличались от родительского на 1

Comment: У одного узла дочерних узлов может быть много. Как все они могут *"отличаться от родительского на 1"*?

Comment: Эээ... А если дочерних узлов много?

Answer (score 2):

Например:

```
public void AssignNodeIdentifiers(Node root)
{
    int currid = 0;
    SetNodeIdentifiersForSubtree(node, ref currid);
}

// классический обход в глубину
void SetNodeIdentifiersForSubtree(Node node, ref int currid)
{
    node.id = currid++;
    foreach (var child in children)
        SetNodeIdentifiersForSubtree(child, ref currid);
}
```

Comment: Слишком общее название метода, не подавайте дурной пример. :)

Comment: @Discord: Согласен!

Answer (score 1):

Обозначьте требования более внятно. Если идентификаторы всех дочерних узлов отличаются от родительского идентификатора на единицу, то они не могут быть уникальными, если потомков более одного.

Для начала можно задать статическое поле `static int globalId = 0`, а в конструкторе инкрементировать его: `id = globalId++`. А от этого уже можно плясать в зависимости от требований. Например, если код может применяться в многопоточных сценариях, то имеет смысл воспользоваться `Interlocked.Increment`.

Если у вас очень жёсткие требования на то, в какой зависимости должны находиться идентификаторы родителей и детей, при этом нужно обновлять структуру и поддерживать зависимости идентификаторов, то один раз просчитать идентификаторы рекурсией, конечно, можно, но вы утомитесь реализовывать все операции, и надо задуматься об альтернативной реализации.

В общем, в отрыве от реальной проблемы решать задачу не имеет смысла.

Comment: Discord, вы путаете определение родительского узла и корневого

Comment: @JDbP Раскройте мысль. И уточните вопрос, вы до сих пор не объяснили, что именно вам надо и зачем.